# Send child items in div to background with z-index, but still make them visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have bunch of those in a loop on my page:

```
<div class="row-container">
    <div role="button" class="row plan-clicked" id="1">
        <div class="col-xs-12 plan-content">
            <div class="col-xs-1"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-users"></i></div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                Test plan 3
            </div>
            <div class="price col-xs-3 pull-right">Only 2999</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`id="1"` changes for every iteration in a loop, and i have click event attached to every id in javascript.

Problem is, that click event fires only when user click "blank" space in div with id. When anything else is clicked, event is not executed.

I have tried to set z-index of `.plan-clicked` to `999 !important` and `.plan-content` to less than that, but it's still same.  I tried setting `.plan-content` to -1, but in that case, it goes down and i can't see it.

How can i fix this?

Comment: How do we debug this ?

Comment: `plan-content`  is **inside** of `plan-clicked`, so both of them are in the same context. Due this, `plan-content` will be with `z-index` of planclicked and all z-index setted to this will be only valid for childrens. To avoid this, you need to create different contexts for both layers

Comment: Bind the elements like `$('#1 *').click();`

Comment: Show how you attach your click handler. Also, you definitely do not need to `have click event attached to every id in javascript`, use selectors - probably, with event delegation, if they are dynamically changed.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by replacing div     `<div role="button" class="row plan-clicked" id="1">` with `<a href..>`

Answer (score 0):

You could set : pointer-events: none; to the child elements and that could work, but this does not work in IE10 or below. But you could use this polyfill. 
https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill

Just an option, which might solve your issue. If your inner elements have background transparent, then in IE it will automatically fall through without the polyfill.